# Heroku-16 for local development only or ok for production?

Tags: heroku, google-cloud-platform, cloud

Is Heroku-16 meant only for local development purposes or is it ok to use it in production? If it's not meant for production, what are the potential problems one might encounter?

I'm looking at taking over an existing application that is using it in production hosted on Google's cloud platform.

Answer (score -1):

As always, the answer is: it depends.

What is your application? What kind of requirements do you have around performance, reliability, backup/recovery, security, etc? What does "production" mean to you? GCP (and the other major cloud platforms) will have much better features to support your application in production vs Heroku.

Disclaimer: I may be biased because I work with AWS and GCP most of the time, but my general impression is that Heroku is primarily for development/testing and is not specifically catered toward production use.

Comment: Thank you but I think you missed the point of the question. I'm not asking about Heroku vs GCP/AWS but specifically Heroku-16 which is a deployable Heroku platform that can be used outside of Heroku itself.